# tornado and postgresql

Tags: python, facebook, postgresql, tornado

I'm using demo from [facebook's tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/blog/blog.py)

But I don't want to use MySQL and trying to replace it with PG
So I went ahead and modified like this :

```
define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("pgsql_host", default="127.0.0.1:5432", help="blog database host")
define("pgsql_database", default="pgdb", help="blog database name")
define("pgsql_user", default="admin", help="blog database user")
define("pgsql_password", default="pgpass", help="blog database password")
```

and

```
        # Have one global connection to the blog DB across all handlers
    self.db = tornado.database.Connection(
        host=options.pgsql_host, database=options.pgsql_database,
        user=options.pgsql_user, password=options.pgsql_password)
```

But app just hangs when I run it, how to properly migrate it to PG?

Actually I get error after some time:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/database.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/database.py", line 101, in reconnect
    self._db = MySQLdb.connect(**self._db_args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

Why is it connecting to MySQL?

Comment: Do you have postgresql wrapper installed (momoko for example) to use with tornado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you can use it with different RDBMS including PostgreSQL?
It uses [torndb](https://github.com/bdarnell/torndb) package which is written to work with MySQL.

So i think that if you want to use it with PostgreSQL you should write your own torndb package for postgresql.

EDIT:
As you can see at [Tornado Wiki](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/wiki/Links) you have to have postgresql wrapper ([momoko](https://github.com/FSX/momoko) or [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/)) there are some links for further study.

EDIT2: Momoko description:
 "An asynchronous Psycopg2 wrapper for Tornado."

Answer (score 3):

`tornado.database` (which will be broken out of Tornado in 3.0) is a lightweight MySQL wrapper. It doesn't support anything other than MySQL.

The good news is, as @sufleR noted, you have some options. You can use [pyscopg](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/) directly, or you can use [momoko](https://github.com/FSX/momoko), an async wrapper for pyscopg.

Comment: +1 for momoko - its actively maintained and works with recent versions of tornado, python and various psycopg2 clones.

Comment: Sadly momoko is no longer actively maintained, doesn't support Tornado 5+ and they have no plans to add it.